# Prolog - a predicate to compare three arguments

Tags: prolog, logic, implication

I am new into prolog and I've already done some coding, but I have a task I cannot handle. Could you please tell me how to describe a working predicate, that compares arg1, arg2 and arg3 and returns yes it arg1>arg2>arg3? Many thanks in advance!

Szymon

Comment: By "returns yes" I assume you mean that it succeeds (which is not, technically "returning a value"). Start with `compare3(X, Y, Z) :- ...` and determine what `...` is based upon the statement: `*`X` > `Y` > `Z` **if** ...*. To say any more than that would be doing all of your work for your. :p

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite easy:

```
compare3(X, Y, Z):-
    X>Y,
    Y>Z.

?- compare3(5,4,3).
true.
```

Keep in mind that you cannot define predicates with an arbitrary number of input parameters (so obviously `compare/3` could be called only with 3 input). To make it more flexible you can insert the element in a list and rewrite it like this

```
myCompare([]).
myCompare([_]):- !.
myCompare([A,B|T]):-
    A>B,
    myCompare([B|T]).

?- myCompare([5,4,3]).
true.
```

Now `myCompare/1` accepts a list and return true if the list is sorted, false otherwise.

Comment: I wish there were people around who would do my homework for me for free when I was in school. ;)

Comment: @lurker i'm still in university and i would like to have people to do my project for free too ;)